# spring batch integration file poller

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-java-config, poller

I am trying to build a spring batch application that starts a job only after a file comes into a directory. For that I need a file poller and something like the snippet found in Spring reference manual:

```
public class FileMessageToJobRequest {
    private Job job;
    private String fileParameterName;

    public void setFileParameterName(String fileParameterName) {
        this.fileParameterName = fileParameterName;
    }

    public void setJob(Job job) {
        this.job = job;
    }

    @Transformer
    public JobLaunchRequest toRequest(Message<File> message) {
        JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder =
        new JobParametersBuilder();

        jobParametersBuilder.addString(fileParameterName,
        message.getPayload().getAbsolutePath());

        return new JobLaunchRequest(job, jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters());
    }
}
```

I would like to manage everything with configuration classes, but I can't really figure out how to make it work.

Comment: I have a similar requirement. If you have the solution to your problem then can you please share. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear. Would be better to have something that works, then some your own PoC or attempt to reach the task.

But anyway that looks like you would like to avoid XML configuration and be only with Java & Annotation Configuration.

For this purpose I suggest you to take a look into [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/overview.html#programming-tips) and find this sample in the [File Support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html#_configuring_with_java_configuration_8) chapter, too:

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "fileInputChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000"))
public MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource() {
     FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
     source.setDirectory(new File(INBOUND_PATH));
     source.setFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.txt"));
     return source;
}
```